# Compare 2nd SQL rows onward values with XML values?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am working on an automation program, where I have a XML request body which has few values and i need to compare these values with SQL data.

I am able to compare 1st SQL row with 1st XML node but don't understand how to compare from 2nd row upwards.

Details sample code given below

Sample Request body in XML format:

```
<Students>
    <Student id="101" course="Computer" Year="2016"/>
    <Student id="102" course="Electrical" Year="2017"/>
    <Student id="103" course="Mechanical" Year="2019"/>
</Students>
```

Sample data returning from SQL:

```
id    course       Year   
==========================
101    Computer       2016
102    Electronics    2017
103    Mechanical     2019


<teststep id="Verify_Student" action ="validate"  description="Validate Student DB" argsvalue="XML_TagValue" >
    <validation id="ProductValidation"  comparisontype="contains">
      <operandexpected>
        <value id="Studentid" valuefrom="db" key="GetAllColumnValuesFromTable" column="id"/>
        <value id="StudentCourse" valuefrom="db" key="GetAllColumnValuesFromTable" column="course"/>
        <value id="Studentyear" valuefrom="db" key="GetAllColumnValuesFromTable" column="Year"/>
      </operandexpected>
      <operandactual>
        <value id="Studentid" valuefrom="previousstep" key="{0}" xpath="//Students/Student/id" attribute="id"/>
        <value id="StudentCourse" valuefrom="previousstep" key="{0}" xpath="//Students/Student/course" attribute="course"/>
        <value id="Studentyear" valuefrom="previousstep" key="{0}" xpath="//Students/Student/Year" attribute="Year"/>
      </operandactual>
    </validation>
  </teststep>
```

I am expecting it will compare XML value and SQL value and if the output will be  matched then it will show pass or if one column mis-match then failed.

Comment: Please show the SQL that you've tried (and how it failed), and what the actual results you want given this sample data. It's hard to help if we don't know exactly what you've tried and what your expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one way to compare DB table and XML request. Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but it will give you a head start.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml_request XML = N'<Students>
    <Student id="101" course="Computer" Year="2016"/>
    <Student id="102" course="Electrical" Year="2017"/>
    <Student id="103" course="Mechanical" Year="2019"/>
</Students>';

DECLARE @mockTbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, course VARCHAR(30), [year] CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO @mockTbl (id, course, [year])
VALUES
(101, 'Computer', '2016')
, (102, 'Electronics', '2017')
, (103, 'Mechanical', '2019');

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS id
        , c.value('@course', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS course
        , c.value('@Year', 'CHAR(4)') AS [year]
    FROM @xml_request.nodes('/Students/Student') AS t(c)
)
(SELECT *, 'no match' AS result FROM rs
EXCEPT
SELECT *, 'no match' FROM @mockTbl)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *, 'match' FROM rs
INTERSECT
SELECT *, 'match' FROM @mockTbl);
```

> Output

```
+-----+------------+------+------------------+
| id  |   course   | year | result           |
+-----+------------+------+------------------+
| 102 | Electrical | 2017 | no match         |
| 101 | Computer   | 2016 | match            |
| 103 | Mechanical | 2019 | match            |
+-----+------------+------+------------------+
```